# Cygwin save package selections for later reinstall

Tags: windows, scripting, cygwin

I was wondering if there is a way to save the current package selections for cygwin for a later reinstall or porting on a different system.

It would be really great to:

- run a command to export a list of installed packages on an existing system
- pass the list to the installer on another system in a way such as `setup-x86_64.exe --list list.txt`

I don't think the setup has such a switch, so even any type of script or batch working in this direction would be just fine.

Since the number of needed packages is very high, it should be unattended in order to consider it as a good solution!

**What would be the best way to accomplish a quick reinstall like this?**

Comment: Not all of the packages might be actually needed for the re-install. In many cases, there are only a few user-selected packages, the rest being the base packages and dependencies. This selection is stored in the `/etc/setup/installed.db` file (the 3rd column is `1` for user-selected packages). If only these packages are re-installed, the setup should automagically install the most recent versions available for the rest of the packages. Some [bugs](https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg165216.html) were reported though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The list of installed packages is available with `cygcheck`. `Setup` does not accept a list option but you can specific the list with `-P`

The following code, when used with `-A` option will create
a crafted `cyg-reinstall-${Arch}.bat` batch file to install all
packages existing in a system.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Create a batch file to reinstall using setup-{ARCH}.exe
# all packages reported as incomplete

print_error=1

if [ $# -eq 1 ]
  then
    if [ $1 == "-I" ]
    then
      lista=$(mktemp)
      cygcheck -c | grep "Incomplete" > $lista
      print_error=0
    fi
    if [ $1 == "-A" ]
    then
      lista=$(mktemp)
      cygcheck -cd | sed -e "1,2d" > $lista
      print_error=0
    fi
fi

if [ $# -eq 2 ]
  then
    if [ $1 == "-f" ]
    then
      lista=$2
      print_error=0
    fi
fi

# error message if options are incorrect.
if [ $print_error -eq 1 ]
then
        echo -n "Usage : " $(basename $0)
        echo " [ -A | -I | -f filelist ]"
        echo "  create cyg-reinstall-{ARC}.bat from"
        echo "  options"
        echo "    -A  :  All packages as reported by cygcheck"
        echo "    -I  :  incomplete packages as reported by cygcheck"
        echo "    -f  :  packages in filelist (one per raw)"
        exit 1
fi

if [ $(arch) == "x86_64" ]
then
  A="x86_64"
else
  A="x86"
fi
# writing header
echo -n -e "setup-${A}.exe  " > cyg-reinstall-${A}.bat

# option  -x remove and  -P install
# for re-install packages we need both
if [ $1 == "-I" ]
then
  awk 'BEGIN{printf(" -x ")} NR==1{printf $1}{printf ",%s", $1}' ${lista} >> cyg-reinstall-${A}.bat
fi

awk 'BEGIN{printf(" -P ")} NR==1{printf $1}{printf ",%s", $1} END { printf "\r\n pause "}' ${lista} >> cyg-reinstall-${A}.bat

# execution permission for the script
chmod +x cyg-reinstall-${A}.bat
```

Comment: Your solution is OUTSTANDING! Just what I was looking for. I just had to edit the resulting batch to add my favourite site `-s` and my LAN's cygwin local-package-dir `-l`. If you could edit your script to ask for such details before building the list it would be PERFECT, because at this point, unattended `-q` can be added too. Also, the batch was produced with three whitespaces between the executable name and the first "-P" switch but this is pure formality.

Comment: I've added my personal preferences such as local dir and preferred local mirror at row 52: `echo ...` of your script. It works like a charm.

Comment: This is very useful, thank you for posting this. After 25 years of cygwin I wish this was easier to do but you are a savior

Comment: Works as expected.

Comment: Didn't work for me with setup 2.924

Comment: maybe due to command length limitation ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/shell-experience/command-line-string-limitation

Answer (score 1):

I recognize that this question is several years old, but I've often found useful information on here from even longer ago, so this might still help someone someday.

The script above did not work for me; I suspect the list was too long, or something of that nature.  So I kept trying things, and I eventually arrived at a shell one-liner that worked correctly by trimming the list to only those items that I had explicitly requested.  The key came from @Andrey's [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829532/cygwin-save-package-selections-for-later-reinstall#comment128648077_46829532):  `/etc/setup/installed.db`!

Here's the command I used:

```bash
(ORIG_PKGS="/path/to/other-cygwin64/etc/setup/installed.db" ; PKGS=$(awk '/ 1$/ {print $1}' "${ORIG_PKGS}") ; PLIST=$(tr '\n' ',' <<< "${PKGS}") ; /setup-x86_64 -q -P "${PLIST%%,}")
```

For readability, here it is split up into multiple lines:

```bash
ORIG_PKGS="/path/to/other-cygwin64/etc/setup/installed.db"
PKGS=$(awk '/ 1$/ {print $1}' "${ORIG_PKGS}")
PLIST=$(tr '\n' ',' <<< "${PKGS}")
/setup-x86_64 -q -P "${PLIST%%,}"
```

All you should need is the `/etc/setup/installed.db` from the previous Cygwin installation; just alter the value of `ORIG_PKGS` with the correct path to that file, and the rest should Just Work®!

Comment: Works very well. I have saved packages to a file: `awk '/ 1$/ {print $1}' "${ORIG_PKGS}" | tr '\n' ',' > cygpackages.list` And then from Windows CLI: `set /p cygpackages=<cygpackages.list` and finally `setup-x86_64.exe -P %cygpackages%`