# How to install cygwin with packages specifed in a packagelist file

Tags: cygwin

I have made a backup of packages that I had installed while installing cygwin before so I have a packagelist file now. Now I wanna install cygwin in an another computer with the same packages involved, but dont know how to do this. please help me. Regards Saeid.

Comment: I have made backup with the command " cygcheck -c -d | sed -e "1,2d" -e 's/ .*\$//' > packagelist "

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829532/cygwin-save-package-selections-for-later-reinstall for answer to same question.