# How can I transfer my cygwin install to another computer and avoid the resource unavailable error?

Tags: cygwin

I have a fresh cygwin 64 bit installation that I created using Cygwin's setup process (setup_x64.exe with --no-admin).  Part of the packages I've installed are 'xfce4', 'openbox' and 'fbpanel'.  My goal was to customize the menu a bit and prepare it for use by other folks on my team.  Having done that, I created a 7zip of the 'C:\cygwin64' directory.  This is something I've had success with previously and yes, I've used the *rebaseall -v* command.

However, with this most recent image, I'm unable to avoid the dreaded 'Resource temporarily unavailable' error when launching a process from the 'fbpanel' when using openbox.  When using xfce4, the X window server starts to come up but the xfce4-panel never shows icons and chews up a ton of cpu.

For those that may ask why not use the setup command on each computer, unfortunately, other members of the team don't have the same access.  Additionally, I want the customizations I've made to stick around without a rather complicated set of procedures.

How I made my starting cygwin image:

1. Ran cygwin setup_x64.exe --no-admin
2. picked the packages I wanted including xfce4, openbox, fbpanel, xterm, ...
3. created my customizations and copied them to /etc/skel
4. created cygwin64.7z by 7zipping the c:\cygwin64 directory

Things I've tried:

1. /bin/rebaseall -v
2. reran the postinstall scripts in /etc/postinstall/*
3. reran the cygwin setup and picked to reinstall a package I already had.

thanks!

Comment: When in the sequence did you run `rebaseall` ?  Before or after using the archive to copy everything to another machine?

Comment: After.   The way I've been testing the situation is: create the zip archive.  Rename c:\cygwin64 to c:\cygwin64_keep, unzip the archive to c:\cygwin64, using dash run rebaseall, startopenbox, which also autostarts fbpanel, inside the panel click on my "term" shortcut.  See error.

Comment: If you're trying it right back on the same computer, you probably have some type of special file or file permission that isn't preserved by the 7z software.

Comment: I wrote a script to capture the before image permissions which I'll apply to the after image once unzipped.  I still need to test it.  In my image there were over 90000 files so the script will take a rather long time to run.  I wonder if there is a better option that 7zip to create the archive such it it retains the permissions as part of the archive.

Comment: Once cygwin is up and running, cpio would probably work well... a pure windows *copy* can be done using robocopy, not sure about an archive.  Probably with the backup program.  Or robocopy into a mounted VHD...

Comment: Have you highlight your `resource unavailable error` and your patches to cygwin mailing list ?

Comment: To duplicate an installation you can use the script at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829532/cygwin-save-package-selections-for-later-reinstall/46830336#46830336

Comment: My bash script that captured perms and applied the perms to the unzipped location was a major bust.  I was in a worse situation than a simple unzip.  The /tmp directory was all jacked up.  I know I have alot to learn but not alot of time to resolve this.  I'm trying a 7zip tar image next to see how that goes (as an experiment).  Then, I'll try the robocopy suggestion.  Unfortunately, robocopy doesn't create a compressed target, but at least it should give me a good backup copy in case I screw something up.  Thanks for the assistance so far!

Comment: I think I'm ready to pull what's left of my hair out.  I attempted to try the windows icacls command to copy the attributes from the good installation to the bad installation but it doesn't want to do it.  I don't have admin rights so I think my only option is to leave a full directory tree out there somewhere.  Ug.  I don't know what else to do from this point.

Comment: The proper way to duplicate an installation is to use setup and install the same packages. Any other solution will screw up the permissions

Comment: The problem I'm facing is my target users won't be able to run setup.  I'm hoping someone can provide the steps to properly set the permissions without needing to use setup.  Maybe I'm being stubborn but I have to believe that what setup is doing should be reproducible from windows natively.