# How to match Cygwin installation across two machines?

Tags: installation, cygwin

Cygwin is currently installed on a desktop machine. I need to install it on a laptop. The installation on desktop was done a long time ago. A long list of packages were installed. Specific version number of these packages must exist otherwise certain things that Cygwin is used for, do not work.

What is the simplest and quickest way to "mirror" the Cygwin installation of the desktop onto the laptop? The setup of Cygwin does not seem to be very user friendly.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829532/cygwin-save-package-selections-for-later-reinstall/46830336#46830336 also on https://www.mail-archive.com/cygwin@cygwin.com/msg163257.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cygwin save package selections for later reinstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46829532/cygwin-save-package-selections-for-later-reinstall)

Comment: I shall try this on Monday